# solving the Integral $ \int_0^{1} \tan ^{-1}(ax) dx$ where $a$ is in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ using u substitution, or integration by parts

Tags: calculus

$$
\int_0^1 \tan ^{-1}(a x) d x \text { where } a \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}
$$

my solution:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& u=\tan ^{-1}(a x) \\
& d u=\frac{a}{1+(a x)^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\frac{1+(a x)^2}{a} d u=d x
$$

for integral limits:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& x=1 \text { so } \tan ^{-1}(a) \\
& x=0 \text { so } 0
\end{aligned}
$$

then:
$$
\int_0^{\tan ^{-1}(a)} u\left(\frac{1+(a x)^2}{a}\right) d u
$$

However my prof said that we should not mix variables , so having x in my integral is a problem but I am not sure how else to do it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to continue with your substitution, consider that $$u = \tan^{-1}(ax)$$ is the same as $$\tan u = ax$$ Could you continue from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration by parts is the most readily apparent method. Notice
$$ \int_0^1 \arctan(ax) \ dx = x\arctan(ax) \Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{ax}{1+a^2x^2} \ dx = \arctan(a) - \int_0^1 \frac{ax}{1+a^2x^2} \ dx.$$ I have no doubt you can take it from here.

Comment: @Fatimah - If you're struggling to proceed, consider $\frac{d}{dx} \ln\left(f(x)\right)$